# Jquery UI Slider Extend

Tags: jquery-ui

i've been googling nearly a day just to get this to work with no luck. How can i achieve from this code

```
$(function () {
  var slider2 = $("#slider2").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    start: function( event, ui ) {
      $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle.ui-state-hover')
        .append('<span class="ui-slider-tooltip">'+ui.value+'</span>');
    },
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $(this).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').text(ui.value);
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

to this code

```
$(function () {
  var slider2 = $("#slider2").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    showTooltip: true
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/epekex/1

Comment: There's no `showTooltip` option as far as I know. Where did you see it? Also, what's wrong with the code you've got?

Comment: yes there is no showTooltip option..  but i want to extend the widget so the first example code can be implement in easier way(example two).. thanks... any idea... i'm new with jquery though